# Using GNU parallel to parallelize script with various arguments

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu

I am interested in running a script in parallel and I've started looking over GNU parallel tool, however I'm having a bit of trouble. My script `doSomething` takes 3 arguments and I would like to run the script in parallel on different values for the arguments. How can I do this?

I've tried: `parallel ./doSomething {1} {2} {3} ::: {0..5} ::: {0..5} ::: {0..5}` but it just seems to hang.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you using any version of GNU parallel packaged with Debian or with Ubuntu? If yes, try to use the `--gnu` option (or, conversely, try to use the `--tollef` option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
parallel --gnu echo ./doSomething {1} {2} {3} ::: {0..5} ::: {0..5} ::: {0..5}
```

If that works as expected, then your command is blocking because `./doSomething` behaves differently when called from GNU Parallel than when it is called directly. One of the reasons why that may happen is if `./doSomething` depends on having an tty connected.